# Selecting distinct through join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

We have 2 tables: users and statuses

The status table has a user_id, status and occured_on. The status is either 'removed' or 'added' and occured_on is the date the user was removed or added.

I need the current added users. That is, all the (distinct) users whose newest status record is 'added'.

I'm using Rails, and have tried:

```
User
  .joins(:statuses)
  .where('statuses.status = ?', 'added')
  .order('statuses.occured_on DESC')
  .uniq
```

Which translates to the SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM users
INNER JOIN statuses
ON statuses.user_id = users.id 
WHERE statuses.status = 'added' 
ORDER BY statuses.occured_on DESC
```

That gives me the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
   LINE 1: ...statuses.status = 'added') ORDER BY statuses.oc...
```

I'd be happy knowing either the Rails code that would work or the straight SQL.

Also, I'd prefer no sub-selects if possible.

Comment: I assume that adding "projects_users.occured_on" to the select (so, both users.* and that column) doesn't meet requirements, since then you are getting each users' transaction history. I think you need a sub select, any reason you are opposed to them?

Comment: I guess a sub-select is my last report. So sure!

Comment: Also note I changed my example to be simpler, but same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Concider the following database schema change:

StatusTable:

```
StatusId
Status
UserId
ActiveFrom
ActiveTo
```

Afterwards you can add additional checks such as:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_from_to CHECK (ActiveFrom <= ActiveTo)
```

Then your query would look something like:

```
   SELECT users.*
   FROM users 
   JOIN statuses ON UserId = users.user_id AND ActiveFrom < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND ActiveTo > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   WHERE statuses.Status = 'active'
```

With such structure you might need to change the way you change statuses, but from my own experience, this structure is much more flexible, and easier to query.

Comment: What if the ActiveTo column is null? What about gaps? For example active from 9/10 to 9/15 and 9/20 to 9/30.

Comment: Well usualy the practice is to set statuses from say 2012/9/10 to 3000/01/01 (set it to inactive, and afterwards, you'll need one function that would cut this interval, and start active interval until given time and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN statuses ON users.id=statuses.user_id WHERE statuses.status='added' ORDER BY statuses.occured_on
```

After clarification, I don't think the schema is well designed for your goal. Can you clarify why you want the status change history contained in that table? My general approach to this would be that active users should be contained in a table called projects_users, containing project_id, user_id. When they are "removed" they should be removed from that table. Logs of the actions - adding and remove users from projects - should be stored in a separate table.

There's no good way that I'm aware of to write this query given your current design. Even if you fixed the errors, this runs error free in MySQL (which is exactly what you have)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.* FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `projects_users`
ON `users`.`id`=`projects_users`.`user_id`
WHERE `status`='added'
ORDER BY `projects_users`.`occured_on` DESC
```

it still won't get you the correct results. The ORDER BY clause will just get you the most recent change to "added", it won't guarantee there is not a more recent "removed" action. To do that you'd need to compare the date of each most recent added record to the date of the most recent removed record, for each user, a nightmare.

Comment: You just rewrote my original query minus the DISTINCT part. This won't raise an error, but definitely won't satisfy my requirements, which are "For project with id 1, I need the current active users." because I'll get the same user multiple times if he/she has multiple projects_users records.

Comment: Well, the query wasn't there when I answered. So the user can have multiple records in projects_users that have the same project_id?

Comment: Yes -> "The status is either 'removed' or 'added' and occured_on is date the user was removed or added to the project."

Comment: Forgive me, I want to ensure I understand this. Does that mean if a User was Added, Removed, Added, then Removed there would exist 4 records with that dates that these actions occurred? So projects_users isn't the members of a project, but a log of the changes of status?

Comment: Exactly. I've changed the example to something simpler.